# Angular2 canceling route transition (when using async resolver)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Recently I started to play with Angular2. 
I started to use resolver like this:

```js
export class SomeResolver implements Resolve<[Day]> {
  constructor(private api: API) {}
  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
   ):Observable<any> {
    return this.api.get('days')
  }
}
```

I implemented basic loader code:

```js
export class LoaderComponent {
  @HostBinding('class.active') active:boolean = false;

  constructor(private router: Router, private location: Location) {
    router.events.subscribe(this.handleRouteChange.bind(this));
  }

  onCancelButtonClicked() {
    this.active = false;
    //Any idea? 
  }

  private handleRouteChange(event: Event) {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      console.log('START');
      this.active = true;
    } else
      console.log('END');
      this.active = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Imagine that `this.api.get('days')` executes slowly and you want to cancel that request like "xhr.abort()" and get back to the previous route.
I tried to use "location.back()" but this route change just joins the router queue. The same with "router.navigate(...)". 
I couldn't find a way to instantaneously cancel the request and get back to the previous route.

Do you have any idea how to address this problem?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39061623/how-to-cancel-route-change-in-angular-2), Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm afraid that canDeactivate runs before resolver starts his work. It doesn't really solve the problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another observable that emits an error after given time and merge it with your request. See an example on the following demo.

I've created here a **stream that emits the error** *before* the request is returned, hence the merged stream ends in error, which results in canceling route transition.

If the value from the request stream came before the the error emitted from the `$timeout` stream, the route would be resolved.
(you can play with this code here: http://jsbin.com/wiyawolete/edit?js,console)

```js
// this stream represents your .get request
const request$ = Rx.Observable.interval(5000).take(1);

// and this is the show-stopper
const timeout$ = Rx.Observable.timer(1000).switchMap(Rx.Observable.throw());

request$.merge(timeout$).take(1)
  // the subscription here is just to show the result.
  // you won't put it in your resolver
  .subscribe(console.log.bind(console), () => console.error('REJECTION'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.7/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Tomek! Your idea helped me. For the record: I needed to create my own Observable with Observable.create and put there listener from loaderservice. Throws errors in console, but works perfectly.