# Is it possible to stop router navigation based on some condition

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular, I want stop the routing when user clicks on **refresh button** or **back button** based on some condition. I don't know whether this is possible, if anybody knows help me

```
constructor(private route: Router) {
    this.route.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .pairwise().subscribe((event) => {
            if (expression === true){
                // stop routing 
            } else {
                // continue routing
            }      
        });
}
```

Can it be possible? If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: Take a look here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#guards

Comment: @R.Richards thank you i learnt lot from this link.

Comment: It looks like, this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41187919.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel route change in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39061623/how-to-cancel-route-change-in-angular-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warn user of unsaved changes before leaving page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922071/warn-user-of-unsaved-changes-before-leaving-page)

Answer (score 60):

I stumbled upon this question quite a bit after the fact, but I hope to help someone else coming here.

The principal candidate for a solution is a route guard.

See here for an explanation:
https://angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes

The relevant part (copied almost verbatim) is this implementation:

```js
import { Injectable }           from '@angular/core';
import { Observable }           from 'rxjs';
import { CanDeactivate,
         ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
         RouterStateSnapshot }  from '@angular/router';

import { MyComponent} from './my-component/my-component.component';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<MyComponent> {

  canDeactivate(
    component: MyComponent,
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    // you can just return true or false synchronously
    if (expression === true) {
      return true;
    }
    // or, you can also handle the guard asynchronously, e.g.
    // asking the user for confirmation.
    return component.dialogService.confirm('Discard changes?');
  }
}
```

Where `MyComponent` is your custom component and `CanDeactivateGuard` is going to be registered in your `AppModule` in the providers section and, more importantly, in your routing config in the `canDeactivate` array property:

```js
{
  path: 'somePath',
  component: MyComponent,
  canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]
},
```

**Edit:**
Given that this question has quite a bit of traction and that many people seems to be requesting a solution to a different but related problem (how to add guards to a set of routes), I'm adding here a small helper function to add a set of guards to all of them:

```js
// the Pick<...> syntax could be extended or replaced with a Partial<Route>
function withGuards<T extends Route | Routes>(input: T,
    guards: Pick<Route, 'canActivate' | 'canDeactivate'>): T {
  const routes: Route[] = Array.isArray(input) ? input : [input];
  for (let route of routes) {
    // if an object already exists, we do not replace the configured guards. meant to allow overrides for specific entries.
    Object.entries(guards).forEach(([prop, guard]) => {
      if (route && !route[prop]) route[prop] = guard;
    });
    if (route?.children) {
      withGuards(route.children, guards);
    }
  }

  return input;
}

// usage:

const route = withGuards({
    path: 'somePath',
    component: MyComponent
  }, {
    canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]
  });
```

This method will inject the guard in all the provided route(s) and in all their nested children, recursively.

Comment: The downside is that we cannot apply guards globally to all routes without adding the guard to each and every route individually.

Comment: @yankee well, if you _really_ need to have your guard applied to every route, you can just preprocess the `ROUTES` constant before passing it into `RoutingModule.forRoot(ROUTES)`. A simple `ROUTES.foreach(r => r.canDeactivate = [ CanDeactivateGuard ])` or something similar would do. You could handle every other case (nested children routes, other guard types) with similar variations on this.

Comment: This does not work anymore. I am getting `NullInjectorError` did I did anything wrong? The only change I did, is that I registered my guard in `RouterModule.forChild` within lazy loaded module, where the component is used.

Comment: @Akxe, this still works. I strongly suspect there is something wrong in your setup. The injector has everything to do with lazy loading, and probably nothing to do with guards. If you can't make it work, open another question!

Comment: In your answer, you never informed, that `CanDeactivateGuard` must be in `providers` array of a NgModule

Comment: That doesn't seem to be very constructive. Every service in Angular (Guards are just a specialized service) need to be included in the Providers or being `providedIn: "root"`. I'm going to update the answer anyway, just in case anyone else had the same problem.

Comment: Is it possible to share code of confirm function of dialogService. As for me async not working. Thanks!

Comment: @AlbertoChiesa This is the best approach if you really need all routes. yet still kind of cluttered in a nested lazy loaded routes scenario. I'd wish for something like `this.Router.events.forEach((event) => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
    event.cancel();
  }
});`

Comment: @MartinEckleben I don't agree. The "code driven" approach you suggest is invisible to other developers looking at the application routes. I have updated the answer with an helper that would be more explicit.

Answer (score 5):

The easy way for me is with skiplocationchange in a new route navigate like this:

```
if(condition === true){

  const currentRoute = this.router.routerState;

  this.router.navigateByUrl(currentRoute.snapshot.url, { skipLocationChange: true });
  // this try to go to currentRoute.url but don't change the location.

}else{
  // do nothing;
}
```

`is a no beautiful method but works`

Answer (score 5):

There is another solution which I invented and it works:

(For lazy people like me who do not want to create guard for handling this)

```
import { NavigationStart, Router } from '@angular/router';
```

In constructor:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.forEach((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        /* write your own condition here */
        if(condition){
          this.router.navigate(['/my-current-route']); 
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Hopefully you won't be lazy enough to change `'/my-current-route'` to your route url.

Comment: This is searching for unexpected problems, in my own experience. When a navigation is running, the router can get finicky in handling new navigation requests. IMHO this is the wrong kind of lazy.

Comment: I won't give a +1 on this one, but I liked the last sentence though. :D

Comment: My colleague left this gem. He's on a different project now. It didn't smell good, so I searched for another solution. I can bet he got it from here, as he is exactly the type that says "it's good because it works". Love the humor in the last sentence :D

Comment: This can also lead to a cancellation of the whole navigation, see [Angular 2: NavigationCancel - Navigation ID 2 is not equal to the current navigation id 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41937115/1456376).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar challenge trying to include a checkbox that would programmatically enable and disable routing.

I tried the solutions of to `navigateByUrl` to the same location but it seemed a bit inconsistent when trying to navigate to any other routes afterwards

So instead I created two route guards, and programmatically reset the route config when the checkbox was toggled

Guards

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class RouterDisableGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate() {
    return false;
  }
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class RouterEnableGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Service

```
this.router.resetConfig(
      this.router.config.map((r) => {
        if (!r.redirectTo) {
          r.canActivate = enabled ? [RouterEnableGuard] : [RouterDisableGuard];
        }
        return r;
      })
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

From the NavigationStart event you can navigate to the same route, which will basically cancel the navigation.

```
router.navigateByUrl(router.url, {  replaceUrl: true });
```

or with other words and more code:

```
this.router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
      .subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => {
        if (event.url == '/move_up') {
          // basically this line stops the navigation to new route
          router.navigateByUrl(router.url, {  replaceUrl: true });
        } else{
          // if you want do other things or leave empty
        }
      });
  }
```

In this case the url /move_up will not navigate to new route.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this problem: I wanted each component to be able to cancel a navigation in some cases according to the component's instance inner state. After fiddling a little, I came up with this (for Angular 17):

In **app.routes.ts** I defined this function called `componentCanDeactivate` that snoops the component and delegates the decision to it if it has a function named `canDeactivateRoute`, otherwise returns `true` (no-op), and then used it in the routes whose component I'd like to empower with this capability:

```
const componentCanDeactivate = <T extends { canDeactivateRoute?: CanDeactivateFn<T> }>(
    component: T,
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
    nextState: RouterStateSnapshot,
) => {
    if (typeof component?.canDeactivateRoute === 'function') {
        return component.canDeactivateRoute(component, currentRoute, currentState, nextState);
    }
    return true;
};

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'my_path1', component: MyComponent1, canDeactivate: [componentCanDeactivate] },
    { path: 'my_path2', component: MyComponent2, canDeactivate: [componentCanDeactivate] },
    { path: 'my_path3', component: MyComponent3, canDeactivate: [componentCanDeactivate] },
]
```

Then, in each component, I implemented the function like that (the logic is just an example):

```
class MyComponent1 {
    //...
    canDeactivateRoute(
        component: MyComponent1,
        currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
        nextState: RouterStateSnapshot,
    ) {
        return confirm(`Do you want to leave this form? You'll lose any changes.`);
    };
}
```

It's been working well.

Answer (score -10):

You can use NavigationStart event like the following code snippet.

```
this.router.events.subscribe( (event: any) => {
   if (event instanceOf NavigationStart) {
      /// Your Logic
   }
})
```

Comment: This is an event handler for when the navigation already started. Would be better to not fire this if you want to prevent the NavigationStart.