# how to prevent page refresh/reload on changing query string in angular 4+?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am adding some query string parameters to my angular route

```
http://localhost:4200/home/transactions?toDate=2019-02-26&fromDate=2018-01-01&startIndex=0&pageSize=20&showCashedOut=true
```

If i change any value in the query parameters from the URL tab it refreshes the page, Is there any way in angular to prevent this behavior? I want to be able to change the value and prevent refresh on the page. I have looked up on stack overflow and other resources

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to store such values in your URL? There are several better ideas to persist or communicate informations through, components/modules/apps.

Comment: Probably because he wants it as an URL that can be bookmarked or send to other people

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the page when changing the url in the Browser URL Tab is inevitable. It can only be prevented with a browser dialog "Do you want to leave this page", but I guess that is not your usecase.

If you want to the change the url in your application, please look at [location.replaceState()](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#replaceState). Alternatively you can implement a [route guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808818/is-it-possible-to-stop-router-navigation-based-on-some-condition) for more custom scenarios.