# How to listen for Angular 2 native page change event and prevent default?

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I listen for the event that is triggered when route change starts? How can I stop that event? It looks as though the event object doesn't have any methods that can stop this [according to the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationStart-class.html).

```
this.router.events
  .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
  .subscribe((event) => {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault(); // NavigationStart doesn't have this method
  });
```

After stopping it, how can I programmatically trigger route change again?

My end goal is to delay the route change for about 1 second to allow page change animations to complete. So, page change animations on exit.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? If you want to prevent navigation, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/39061623/3001761. Why do you want to start it again afterwards?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Could you give a [mcve] that includes the context? Otherwise people end up solving an http://xyproblem.info.

Comment: Add a click event that uses a timer, then when that timer runs out, you navigate with this.router.navigate([route])

Comment: So something like `<a hrefDelay="/page">page</href>` with my own directive? @DavidAguirre

Comment: in the HTML it would be (click)="timedFunction()" and the function would carry out a timed animation and route after it has completed.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! You can post as answer. I'll rephrase the question if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the HTML it would be:

```
(click)="timedFunction()"
```

and the function would carry out a timed animation and route after it has completed.

After the time animation completes:

```
this.router.navigate([route])
```

Answer (score -1):

Yo don't need to handle this case manually,
Angular will do this for you

just use [Route resolver]
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Resolve-interface.html

the result of this function can be an observable o promise
the page will be loaded when this promise resolved or observable finished

the demo for delaying page load: http://embed.plnkr.co/u2qR9J/

but to answer your first question related to registering event see this:
[Show loading screen when navigating between routes in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069609/show-loading-screen-when-navigating-between-routes-in-angular-2)

start the animation in [Route resolver] and resolve the promise when the animation finished

Comment: This has some potentially useful information but consists mainly of off site links. Please edit to show how the OP could apply these ideas to solve their problem.